# The process of obtaining Bessel's identity.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $\{u_j\}^n_{j=1}$ is an orthonormal set.

Then why can every $f \in H$ , where $H$ is a Hilbert space, be written as $f=f_\parallel + f_\perp$ where $f_\parallel =\sum^n _{j=1} \langle u_j,f \rangle u_j$ ?

How can $f=f_\parallel + f_\perp$ be interpreted?

How can  $f_\parallel =\sum^n _{j=1} \langle u_j,f \rangle u_j$ be interpreted?

From $$||f||^2 =\sum^n _{j=1} |\langle u_j ,f \rangle |^2 +||f_\perp||^2$$ how do we obtain Bessel's inequality which is $$\sum^n _{j=1} | \langle u_j ,f \rangle|^2 \leq ||f||^2$$

Comment: possible duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512018/a-problem-with-a-proof-of-bessels-inequality-and-how-to-get-parsevals-identit?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any linearly-independent set $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ in an inner product space $X$, and given $f\in X$ it is always possible to choose scalars $\{ \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$ such that
$$
    \left( f - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j v_j\right) \perp v_k,\;\;\; 1 \le k \le n.
$$
This represents a set of $n$ equations in the $n$ unknowns $\{ a_j \}_{j=1}^{n}$. You can show that the resulting coefficient matrix has a trivial null space; so you end up with a unique set of scalars $\{ \alpha_j \}_{j=1}^{n}$. However, an easy solution is found in the case that $\{ v_j\}_{j=1}^{n}$ is an orthonormal subset. In that case the orthogonality conditions above reduce to
$$
                   \langle f,v_k\rangle -\alpha_k = 0,\;\;\; k=1,2,\cdots,n.
$$
Therefore, $f-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\langle f,v_k\rangle v_k$ is orthogonal to every $v_j$. That leads to the orthogonal vector decomposition
$$
               f = \left(f - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle f,v_j\rangle v_j\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle f,v_j\rangle v_j.
$$
The two vectors on the right are mutually orthogonal. The first vector is orthogonal to every vector in the linear span of $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ and the second vector is in the same linear span. Therefore,
\begin{align}
          \|f\|^2 & = \left\|f - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle f,v_j\rangle v_j\right\|^2 + \left\|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle f,v_j\rangle v_j\right\|^2 \\
    & = \left\|f - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle f,v_j\rangle v_j\right\|^2 +\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\langle f,\alpha_j\rangle|^2. \\
    & \ge \sum_{j=1}^{n}|\langle f,\alpha_j\rangle|^2.
\end{align}